# Framework7 + angular.js ng-include route error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-framework-7

guys.
I am using Framework7 with Angular.js and everything works fine. But when I try to use ng-include in one of my pages, my app got broken. I realized that url becomes wrong.
Before I call the page which has ng-include, my route is:
app/view/index.html#!/menu.html (and it's OK)
After my page with ng-include load, I got the follow url:
app/view/index.html#/!/requestcategories.html (with a slash between #! – which seems wrong)
My code:

```
<script type=“text/ng-template” id=“recursiveitem”>
<span>Test</span>
</script>

<div data-ng-include=“'recursive_item'”></div>
```

Could you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Angular.JS and Framework7 recently and it works fine again. Probably It was a bug.